# Flask-SQLAlchemy (mssql+pyodbc) and Existing Models with Blueprint

Tags: sql-server, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have this following Flask application/folder structure in python3.6 Enviroment:

```
site/
   __init__.py
   models.py
   static/
   templates/
     dashboard/
       index.html
     login/
       index.html
   views/
     __init__.py
     login.py
config.py
run.py
```

My files looks like this:

## run.py

```
from site import app
app.run()
```

## config.py

```
class BaseConfig(object):
  DEBUG = False
  TESTING = False
  WFT_CSRF_ENABLED = True

class DevConfig(BaseConfig):
  DEBUG = True
  SECRET_KEY = 'dev'
  SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};SERVER=myServer;DATABASE=myDB;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=yes'
  SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

## site/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config.DevConfig')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from site.views import login
app.register_blueprint(login.mod)
```

## site/views/login.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

mod = Blueprint('login', __name__)

@mod.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('login/index.html')
```

## site/models.py

```
class User(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['users']

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

what i am trying to do is to connect and use a existing model in my ms-sql database which is called user.

I am very new with Flask, Flask-SQLAlchemy, Blueprint and Python and I am stucked on how to use the db.Model in my login.py. How to achieved this in a Blueprint paradigm?

Any help and direction will be much appriciated and thanks for the help in advanced!

regards,
maki

Answer (score 1):

you can add the following lines to your login.py:

```
from site import db
from site.models import User
```

to add an new user to the database you can use this :

```
new_user = User()
db.session.add(new_user)
db.session.commit()
```

and add this in your user table :

```
_tablename__ = 'user'
```

you will need to change you database URI in the config by following the syntax suggested in the [flask_sqlalchemy doc](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/config/)

replace what you have by this :

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI : mysql://username:password@server_adress/db_name
```

for user authentification i can suggest you [flask_login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: hello @Espoir, thanks for the quick reply but im having some errors adding the 2 lines of code from the top.

`TypeError: 'immutabledict' object is not callable`

Comment: File "run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mis_site import app
File "...\site\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from mis_site.views import login
File "C:\Users\mark.manalo\dev\python36\mis_site\mis_site\views\login.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mis_site.models import User
  File "...\site\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class User(db.Model):
  File "...\site\models.py", line 6, in User
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables('users')
TypeError: 'immutabledict' object is not callable

Comment: is this correct?
`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};SERVER=myServer;DATABASE=myDB;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=yes'`

Comment: check I have edited my answer, in other to help you  with the erro you are getting , find more here about the uRI http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/config/

Comment: hi there @Espoir! how can i change my DATABASE_URI to suit mssql+pyodc? thanks

Comment: I"m not familiar wirh pyodbc but with sql achemy you doen't need to use it ! just use the URI as suggest in sqlalchemy doc

Comment: Its so frustrating all the suggestions you made is not working at all